# Can't rename array fields to FIELDNAME type on paginated results

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, zend-framework2, propel2

Only one thing I need is to rename all result fields from PHPNAME type into FIELDNAME. I'm running such query:

```
$members = MemberQuery::create()->filterByOrganizerId($organizerId)
        ->setFormatter($formatter)
        ->useTableOneQuery()
            ->useTableTwoQuery()
                ->where('TableTwo.Status != ?', TableTwo::STATUS_FAILED)
            ->endUse()
        ->endUse()
        ->groupById()
        ->paginate($page, $pageSize);
```

Where `$formatter` is:

```
    $arrayDataFetcher = new ArrayDataFetcher([]);
    $arrayDataFetcher->setIndexType(TableMap::TYPE_FIELDNAME);

    $formatter= new ArrayFormatter();
    $formatter->setDataFetcher($arrayDataFetcher);
```

But every array is still having PHPNAME fieldnames. When I do not paginate results and just using `find()` I can simply use `toArray` on result and everything is okay, but I can't figure out how to do the same with paginated results

Answer (score 0):

solution is pretty easy. Just use `toArray()` on your result. Do not trust autocomplete. IDE do not shows that method, but it exists! Trust documentation, check [here](http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/model-criteria.html#paginating-results), and you will see comment that paginated results behave like collection, that's exactly what we need.